# Different output by openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have been asking myself, how to interpret the output of openssl regarding certificates, depending on the option (-text or -purpose). Sometimes it is not clear to me, whether - for example - a certificate is meant to be a CA or not.

Example:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert1.pem -purpose -noout
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
...
```

But:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert1.pem -text -noout | grep CA
```

This shows no result. However:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert2.pem -purpose -noout 
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : Yes
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : Yes
...
```

And:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert2.pem -text -noout | grep CA
CA:TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the limited output that you provide, it does seem that your `cert1.pem` is of type `X509v1`. As such, its `-text` output does not contain the `X509v3` extension that show up in your `grep` result for `cert2.pem`.

Some support for this hypothesis starts at the output for `cert1.pem`, which includes

```
SSL client CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
```

The OpenSSL documentation around the meaning of this warning is limited, but by checking its source code, starting at the `apps/x509.c` application, traces back to [the following function](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1d/crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c#L524):

```
static int check_ca(const X509 *x)
{
    /* keyUsage if present should allow cert signing */
    if (ku_reject(x, KU_KEY_CERT_SIGN))
        return 0;
    if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_BCONS) {
        if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_CA)
            return 1;
        /* If basicConstraints says not a CA then say so */
        else
            return 0;
    } else {
        /* we support V1 roots for...  uh, I don't really know why. */
        if ((x->ex_flags & V1_ROOT) == V1_ROOT)
            return 3;
        /*
         * If key usage present it must have certSign so tolerate it
         */
        else if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_KUSAGE)
            return 4;
        /* Older certificates could have Netscape-specific CA types */
        else if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_NSCERT && x->ex_nscert & NS_ANY_CA)
            return 5;
        /* can this still be regarded a CA certificate?  I doubt it */
        return 0;
    }
}
```

where you see code value `3` show up.

To verify whether this is the situation, just look at the first line in your text dump of the different certs, which will look like this:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
```

---

Going back to [the X509 tool documentation page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html), the following now makes sense:

> If the certificate is a V1 certificate (and thus has no extensions)
>   and it is self signed it is also assumed to be a CA but a warning is
>   again given: this is to work around the problem of Verisign roots
>   which are V1 self signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

From the [x509 documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html):

> SSL Client CA
>
> The extended key usage extension must be absent or include the "web client authentication" OID. Netscape certificate type must be absent or it must have the SSL CA bit set: this is used as a work around if the basicConstraints extension is absent.

It looks like your certificate has neither x509v3 extensions (basicConstraints nor extendedUsage). As @Reinier-Torenbeek stated, it means that your certificate is of x509 version 1 type.